# Php session in a chat, browser crash

Tags: php, session, browser, crash

I'm Italian, and i'm not good in English, but I Try to explain what i want to ask to you :)

I'd want to ask you a question about PHP and Sessions stored on the server.

I'm making a Play by chat online game using php and mysql. 
What I need is to detect, using php, expired sessions for inactivity.

While an user is logging into the game, I update a table on a DB . This column that I update is the timestamp of the latest action done by the user. Then, i start a session for the client X. If this column is empty, it means that the user is logged off .

If an user do the logout correctly ( a button inside the game ), with php i destroy the session and i update the column of the DB with an empty timestamp, so the user results correctly logged off, but if there is a crash of the browser?
How can I detect that a session has been destroyed by the crash of the browser?

Thank you :)

Comment: If it is different than the last updated?

Comment: it means that the user is doing something ( like going to another chat, reading private messages, etc ) ...

Answer (score 0):

you could store the connection ID in a seperate table, run a loop that periodically checks those connections for messages the client periodically would sent to denote activity
if the time difference is larger than the message update interval by a certain margin, you would drop the connection and/or update the tables

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a "timeout", for example 10 minutes (600sec)
So, for any action of a user you check if he is current active by the difference of date_last_action and now().

For exampre.

> Login :  2014-03-27 15:49:00
>
> Last action: 2014-03-27 15:51:00  (only 2 minutes from the last action
>   [login])
>
> Last action: 2014-03-27 16:21:00  (over time, so clear the db record,
>   delete his session)

```
$date_now = time(); 
$date= DATA VALUE OF LAST CURRENT USER ACTION;
$date1 = time();
$date2 = mktime($hh,$ii,$ss,$mm,$gg,$aaaa);

$dateDiff    = $date1 - $date2;
$fullDays = floor($dateDiff/(60*60*24));
$fullHours = floor(($dateDiff-($fullDays*60*60*24))/(60*60));
$fullMinutes = floor(($dateDiff-($fullDays*60*60*24)-($fullHours*60*60))/60);

$deadline_in_minutes=10;

if($fullMinutes>$deadline_in_minutes)   
    {
       //do logout clear session
    }
```

Ciao!

Comment: Ma sei italiano, se mi rispondevi in italiano mi facevi un favore :D

Comunque ... fondamentalmente potrei anche farlo, però io ho messo che di default, se un utente sta parcheggiato nel gioco per piu di mezzora, viene sloggato e viene buttato fuori dal gioco, quindi a me servirebbe un meccanismo che riconosce se un utente è crashato dal gioco , in modo da fare l'update sulla tabella e schiaffarlo offline .. Non so se mi sono spiegato :D

Grazie :)